# Does there always exist a regular curve connecting two points in an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, curves-and-surfaces

As the title says, given $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and connected and $x, y\in A$, I am looking for a continuous curve $\gamma:[0, 1]\rightarrow A$ which is differentiable in $(0,1)$ with $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$ for $t\in (0, 1)$.

I know that $x, y$ can be connected by a curve which is regular except at a finite number of point (the union of segments), but here I also need differentiability of the curve in any point, and that it is regular.

I don't know any differential geometry, so I'd prefer proofs that only use topology/real analysis. Thanks.

Comment: The usual argument that the set of points $y$ that can be reached in this way from a fixed $x$ is open and closed seems to work just fine with your extra requirements on $\gamma$ also.

Comment: Alternatively, start with a polygonal path (as you mentioned), and since $A$ is open, you have enough room to fix it at the gluing points to obtain a path of the desired type.

Comment: I think your question would have been better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let $\alpha, \beta: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be two regular curves that intersect at $c\in (a,b)$. Let $\eta:(a,b)\to [0,1]$ be an increasing smooth function that equals $0$ on $(a,c-\epsilon)$ and $1$ on $(c+\epsilon,b)$. Then the curve $\gamma(t) = (1-\eta(t))\alpha(t) + \eta(t) \beta(t)$ is obviously smooth, equals $\alpha$ before $c-\epsilon$, equals $\beta$ after $c+\epsilon$, and by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small can be made to remain within a $\delta$ neighborhood of $\alpha \cup \beta$. // Apply this procedure to smooth out your corners.